# InputHelper email field with default domain

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have a simple page that has only one input field where users put their email address in order to pre-register. But the page layout is designed so the user only inserts the left part of his email. (We'll only accept users with a specific email domain).

So the page layout (the email input part) would look something like:

[INPUT BOX] @ defaultdomain.com

The question is: I created a model called PreRegistration mapped to the respective table on the DB. The only thing I'm storing there so far is the inserted email. So in the validator of the Model I have this code:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Email field cannot be empty'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'The email is not valid.'
        )   
    )
);
```

And in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
        'class' => 'input_box',
        'value' => $input_box_default_text,
        'id' => 'email',
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
    ));
```

The problem is that the validator is validating the text field expecting the user to insert a regular email with the domain (duh, of course). What can I do in order for cakephp validate the text field in conjunction with the default domain?

Comment: simply `$_POST['email'] .= '@ defaultdomain.com'`, before validation starts

Comment: btw, please always mention your exact CakePHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either modify the data as suggested by @cske (but modify `Controller::$request::$data` or `Model::$data` instead of `$_POST`), ie append the domain part to the user input before saving/validating, and consequently store the complete email address in the database, or use a custom validation rule that uses the domain part only for validation purposes, something like:

```
App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');

...

public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Email field cannot be empty'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('validatePreRegistrationEmail'),
            'message' => 'The email is not valid.'
        )   
    )
);

...

public function validatePreRegistrationEmail($data)
{
    $email = current(array_values($data)) . '@defaultdomain.com';
    return Validation::email($email);
}
```